# Get image from Axios and send as Form Data to Wordpress API in a Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, wordpress, axios, google-cloud-functions, multipartform-data

What I'm trying to accomplish is using a **Firebase Cloud Function (Node.js)** to:

**First** download an image from an url (f.eg. from unsplash.com) using an `axios.get()` request

**Secondly** take that image and upload it to a **Wordpress** site using the [Wordpress Rest API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/media/)

The problem seems (to me) to be that the `formData` doesnt actually append any data, but the `axios.get()` request actually does indeed retrieve a buffered image it seems. Maybe its something wrong I'm doing with the Node.js library [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) or maybe I get the image in the wrong encoding? This is my best (but unsuccessfull) attempt:

```
async function uploadMediaToWordpress() {
  var FormData = require("form-data");

    var formData = new FormData();
    var response = await axios.get(
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1610303785445-41db41838e3e?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      { responseType: "arraybuffer" }
    );
    formData.append("file", response.data);

    try {
      var uploadedMedia = await axios.post("https://wordpresssite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media",
        formData, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Disposition": 'form-data; filename="example.jpeg"',
            "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
            Authorization: "Bearer <jwt_token>",
          },
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError("failed-precondition", "WP media upload failed");
    }
    return uploadedMedia.data;
}
```

I have previously successfully uploaded an image to **Wordpress** with **Javascript in a browser** like this:

```
  async function uploadMediaToWordpress() {
      let formData = new FormData();
      const response = await fetch("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1610303785445-41db41838e3e?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80");
      const blob = await response.blob();
      const file = new File([blob], "image.jpeg", { type: blob.type }); 

      formData.append("file", file);
      var uploadedMedia = await axios.post("https://wordpresssite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media",
        formData, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Disposition": 'form-data; filename="example.jpeg"',
            "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
            Authorization: "Bearer <jwt_token>",
          },
      });
      return uploadedMedia.data;
  },
```

I have tried the last couple of days to get this to work but cannot for the life of me seem to get it right. Any pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try without `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` header in your request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "regular" JavaScript code (used in a browser) works because the image is sent as a file (see the `new File` in your code), but your Node.js code is not really doing that, e.g. the `Content-Type` value is wrong which should be `multipart/form-data; boundary=----.....`. Nonetheless, instead of trying (hard) with the `arraybuffer` response, I suggest you to use stream just as in the [axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#form-data) and [form-data documentation](https://github.com/form-data/form-data#axios).

So in your case, you'd want to:

1. Set `stream` as the `responseType`:

   ```js
   axios.get(
       'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1610303785445-41db41838e3e?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80',
       { responseType: 'stream' }
   )
   ```
2. Use [`formData.getHeaders()`](https://github.com/form-data/form-data#headers-getheaders-headers-userheaders-) in the `headers` of your file upload request (to the `/wp/v2/media` endpoint):

   ```js
   axios.post( 'https://wordpresssite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media', formData, {
       headers: {
           ...formData.getHeaders(),
           Authorization: 'Bearer ...'
       },
   } )
   ```
3. And because the remote image from Unsplash.com does not use a static name (e.g. `image-name.jpg`), then you'll need to set the name when you call `formData.append()`:

   ```js
   formData.append( 'file', response.data, 'your-custom-image-name.jpeg' );
   ```

I hope that helps, which worked fine for me (using the `node` command for Node.js version 14.15.4, the latest release as of writing).

Comment: Thank you for this explaination, its working now! One question, is there anyway to know the file extension of the image I get from Unsplash? Or can I somehow force it into a jpg or similar?

Comment: You can use the [mime package](https://github.com/broofa/mime), then get the extension using `mime.getExtension( response.headers['content-type'] )`. As for the "force it into a jpg", I'm not sure yet about that, so maybe you want to ask that in another question.. :)

Comment: Thank you for that, easy and nice solution! :)